# Refreshing page - Ajax submission after Logging In

Tags: jquery

Server side:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username or password';
    }
    else if (user_exists($username)===false){
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username in our database.';
    }
    else if (user_active($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Activate your account.';
    }   else    {
        $login = login($username,$password);
        if ($login === false){
            $errors[] = 'Incorrect combination.';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            $errors[] = 'success';
        }
    }
}else {
    $errors[] = 'No data received!';
}
output_errors($errors);
?>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#login").click(function(){
    $.post($('#loginform').attr("action"), $('#loginform').serializeArray(), function(data) {
                if(data == 'success'){
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { location.reload(true); });
                }else {
                    $('#loginmsg').html(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is, it is not identifying the 'data' when I put it on the if statement. There is no problem with logging in but the page is not refreshing. Please help. Thanks.

Update: I tried the location reload without AjaxStop, but it didn't work. All I want is to refresh the page only if it is a 'success'

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log( data ); before youf if condition...

Comment: I get the echo messages from the php based on wat im entering in the input boxes

Answer (score 0):

try without `ajaxStop`, e.g.:

```
if(data == 'success') location.reload(true);
```

If you're reloading a page - why wait for the requests to complete?

Also - make sure you don't send back any other invisible characters from php.
It's a good practice to remove the ending tag `?>`, to help with that.

Comment: can you put `console.log(data)` before the `if` statement and see what the `data` value is?

Comment: I get the echo messages from the php based on wat im entering in the input boxes

Comment: @Yoosuf can you expose your `output_errors` function? maybe you're sending back "success" with some invisible characters (new line or something)? that's why the condition fails.